# Query.h in Windows 10.0.16299.0 prints syntax errors?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, syntax, syntax-error

For some reason after updating to the latest version of Windows 10 build, Query.h file fails to compile with my C++ code! We use Query for our FPS time-step counter which is vital for any type of game engine, however since the transmission from version 10.0.15063.0 to 10.0.16299.0, we get the following error messages when attempting to build the vs project:

1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\query.h(262): error C2059: syntax error: '||'

1>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.16299.0\um\query.h(262): error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Is anyone else getting the same issue? It's fundamental for us to use Query.h as it keeps our frame count ticking at a constant speed via high-res counters!

I hope someone can point me to the right direction here.

Thanks.

William.

Answer (score 0):

The file itself contains an explanation:

```
// NOTE: When using the /permissive- compiler switch the below structure
// will not compile due to the case(RTOr) member 'or'. Please compile without
// the /permissive- switch

struct tagRESTRICTION
    {
    ULONG rt;
    ULONG weight;
    /* [switch_is][switch_type] */ union _URes
        {
        /* [case()] */ NODERESTRICTION ar;
        /* [case()] */ NODERESTRICTION or;       // Line 262
        /* [case()] */ NODERESTRICTION pxr;
        /* [case()] */ VECTORRESTRICTION vr;
        /* [case()] */ NOTRESTRICTION nr;
        /* [case()] */ CONTENTRESTRICTION cr;
        /* [case()] */ NATLANGUAGERESTRICTION nlr;
        /* [case()] */ PROPERTYRESTRICTION pr;
        /* [default] */  /* Empty union arm */ 
        }   res;
    } ;
```

Comment: Right, but in other projects I get no syntax errors at all. So strange!

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed** I just deleted line 262:

/* [case()] */ NODERESTRICTION or;

Latest version treats "or" as a variable now. Thanks for letting us know Microsoft! :D

Comment: I believe `or` is an alternative `operator ||` name that became a keyword in recent standard.

Comment: Is it quite new then?

Comment: It is not that new, but it dwelled as a macro defined in some rarely included header for most of the time.

Comment: I hope Microsoft fixes this conflict in future updates.